# How to implement Google Consumer Survery in my magento site?

Tags: magento, survey

I need to implement Google survey for my magento site. Is it a freely available one? What are the steps that I need to follow to implement this? I can't get any proper information from this link: http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/home

Comment: i think this is the link http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/website_owners

Comment: Fine i hope it will be work.can you please send me the path to implement the script @SKV

Comment: Priya login to your gmail account and visit following links http://www.google.com/insights/consumersurveys/websat?site=uqa6yqwrxl4hz7irtqogl4xzva and https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/3184807#setup

Comment: Yes already i have visited and done all the steps.They asked to input the code snippet we got for google survey just before the closing </head> tag.I need the file path to input this code.@SKV

Comment: From this link https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/3184807#setup kindly refer 4th point in Survey Setup and Code Placement Tips section.@SKV

Comment: do you mean you want to know the file name where you can find </head> tag and place the code ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45787/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-skv)